# How do I get a 3G USB modem to work?

Tags: 10.04, configuration, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

Since at least Jaunty, I've tried to get my wife's 3G USB modem to work on Ubuntu, always with the same result - instant, complete system freeze.

I've tried installing`wvdial and usb-modeswitch, I've read tons of documentation but it gets quite disjointed from one release to the next, nothing works. I can't run lsusb because the system hangs immediately.

I'm using Lucid and it's a Rogers "Rocket Stick" (in Canada)

Comment: The first stop should be, to figure out which chipset the stick is using and which driver is loaded (that causes the freeze). You could try running "sudo dmesg | tail -f" in a terminal while plugging in the stick. That might also help identifying the problem.

Comment: Does your system freeze when running lsusb even when the modem.is not plunged in? If so you probably need to debug your usb controller first.

Comment: No, it freezes when I plug the modem in. Instantly, no chance to run lsusb or anything else.

Comment: Except I can't run anything because the system freezes right away.

Answer (score 2):

Try this “automagic” script: [sakis3g](http://www.sakis3g.org/). No need to install anything, just run the script; it will guide you through menus.

After you make it work, you can create a small script calling the `sakis3g-script` having set up some environment variables for your convenience. Here follows mine:

```
export BAUD=MAX MODEM=1bbb:0000 APN=3g-internet SIM_PIN=1234
(sakis3g-script helper&)&
```

The $MODEM is the vendor-id:product-id code so I don't have to select it everytime I start the `sakis3g-script`; $APN is your provider's suggested login name; the SIM_PIN is rather obvious.

See also [that question](https://superuser.com/questions/165635) in SuperUser.

Answer (score -1):

The real answer is to start with a supported device. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager for a list of working devices.