# How to install TP-Link MA180 on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.10, network-manager, usb-modem, 3g, usb-modeswitch

I just bought the 3G Modem TP-Link MA180 and I try to install it on Ubuntu 12.10.
Problem : Network Manager does not detect it. I saw on the web that `usb-modeswith` is supposed to handle it, but I don't know how to configure it.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a 3G USB modem to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3084/how-do-i-get-a-3g-usb-modem-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

May 6, 2014. Here is another particular solution to this problem. I inserted a micro SD memory card into the corresponding slot of TP-Link MA180, with UNetbootin put on it Ubuntu 12.04, and had my Acer AOD270 booted into this live. It did do it, and ... there was also a great pleasant surprise to me: on the first Ubuntu screen was a little window asking for the PIN code of my SIM card! ... I gave it, and there emerged an application asking for the data necessary to establish the Internet connection. So, I could have connection apparently without any previous installation of the TP-Link software! ... I can also tell you that the Ubuntu connection was faster than that with Windows 7. Then, leaving TP-Link active, I rebooted into my HDD Ubuntu. There, I could have Internet access with the same procedure.

May 7, 2014. Now, I can access the Internet from Ubuntu with TP-Link MA180 - even without the micro SD card - on my dual-boot, Ubuntu-Windows system in a simpler way: 1) boot into HDD Windows 7, and establish a greenly blinking network connection by just giving the PIN code; 2) with TP-Link installed (I even removed it for a few seconds), reboot into HDD Ubuntu, which asks for the PIN code on its first screen (the application does not emerge any longer).

Probably, there are more similar manners to gain Internet access with TP-Link from Ubuntu.